# APP_CONFIG["value"] not working inside ActionMailer mail templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, app-config, actionmailer

**Using APP_CONFIG to store values for system-wide access, works great but not for ActionMailer email views.** *Does anyone knows how to fix this?*

In load_config.rb (config folder) i load it like:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/application.yml")[Rails.env]
```

Then in my Mailer views (HAML) I try to use them like regularly in my application like:

```
Welcome to our application named:
= APP_CONFIG['app_name']
```

How would i get access to all my APP_CONFIG values inside action mailer views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
default: &default
  app_name:         "My APP"
  app_mail:         "info@..."

development:
  <<: *default
  ...

production:
  <<: *default
  ...
```

The problem was it was using the RAILS_ENV and I had not merged the default section into the production and development mode, like this its clean and you can just do APP_CONFIG["any_var"] having the default (global) ones to store google analytics etc and the ENV specific ones under development and production :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to something like this:

app/controllers/user_controller.rb

```
def some_method
  app_name = APP_CONFIG['app_name']
  UserMailer.welcome_mail(app_name).deliver
end
```

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "info@mypage.com"
  def welcome_mail(app_name)
    @app_name = app_name
    mail(:to => "test@mypage.com", :subject => "[system] User Welcome!")
  end
end
```

app/views/user_mailer/welcome_mail.html.haml

```
%p Welcome to our application named:
=@app_name
```

I think it should work.